# Jetty not getting stopped by service script on Linux

Tags: linux, jetty

The jetty.sh script included in the tar.gz distribution of Jetty 8 seems to be broken.

Starting jetty works fine, but after executing

```
sudo ./jetty.sh stop
```

there is still a job hanging around.

The reason is that during startup two processes are created, the one for start.jar created by jetty.sh, but also a second one. However, only the PID of the start.jar startup is recorded. Therefore, during stopping only this part of the jetty runtime processes gets stopped.

There are similar questions here on Stackoverflow. For example, [in a very simple upstart script is provided](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22099/want-to-make-an-upstart-script-need-help-and-advice), which is also suffering from the same problem described above.

Does anyone know how to fix the script so that both processes get killed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second process is started because your start.ini is using the "--exec" option.

This is an advanced option for configurations that require advanced changes to the JVM, such as specifying bootclasspath.

Most people do not need this functionality.

Simply removing the "--exec" from the start.ini prevents the second process from starting.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the script by manually killing all child processes first. Here is the diff:

```
--- /etc/init.d/jetty   2012-05-29 12:59:09.439511236 +0200
+++ jetty.sh    2012-05-29 12:58:13.615513127 +0200 @@ -461,11 +461,23 @@
   stop)
     echo -n "Stopping Jetty: "
     if type start-stop-daemon > /dev/null 2>&1; then
       echo $JETTY_PID

+      # FIXME: start-stop-daemon isn't killing child process
+      JETTY_PID_NO=`cat "$JETTY_PID"`
+      for child_pid in `ps -o pid --no-headers --ppid $JETTY_PID_NO`
+      do
+        kill -HUP $child_pid
+      done
       start-stop-daemon -K -p"$JETTY_PID" -d"$JETTY_HOME" -a "$JAVA" -s HUP

       TIMEOUT=30
       while running "$JETTY_PID"; do
         if (( TIMEOUT-- == 0 )); then
+          for child_pid in `ps -o pid --no-headers --ppid $JETTY_PID_NO`
+          do
+            kill -KILL $child_pid
+          done
           start-stop-daemon -K -p"$JETTY_PID" -d"$JETTY_HOME" -a "$JAVA" -s KILL
         fi
```